# How to decorate a function in C++

Tags: c++11, lambda, python-decorators

I would like to achieve the following

```
#include <iostream>
unsigned foo(int i) {return i;};
unsigned bar(unsigned(*p)()) {/*Do important work*/return p();};
int main(void){
    int integer = 42;
    auto lambda = [integer] () -> unsigned {return foo(integer);};
    unsigned number = bar(lambda);
    std::cout << number << std::endl;
}
```

That is, `bar` is expecting a pointer to function with no arguments and returning unsigned. I can easily write a wrapper `unsigned baz() {return foo(42);};`and pass that one to `bar()`, but this has two drawbacks

- it's a separate function, while I would prefer to construct the wrapper inline
- I have to write a new wrapper for each expected value of `integer.

The idea is that `bar()` is doing some work, in the process invoking the function, that was passed to it. I have a suitable function, but it has an extra argument. That extra argument, however, is known at the point of passing the function to `bar()`.

Is there a way to pull this off, or should I forget this approach and use templates? I have control over changing the interface (e.g. change the function pointer argument to std::function).`

Comment: Can `bar` be changed to take `std::function<unsinged()>` as a parameter instead? That'd do what you want.

Comment: Only a lambda that doesn't have any captures can be used as a function pointer, see e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#ClosureType::operator_ret.28.2A.29.28params.29.28.29). Either use templates or `std::function`.

Comment: Unrelated: you should get out of the habit of writing `unsigned` alone. It reads like crap. `unsigned` what? "unsigned" isn't a noun.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, how can templates be used to solve my problem? If I make `foo()` template, the lambda still needs to capture `integer`, in order to select the template version of `foo()`.

Comment: No you make *`bar`* a template: `template<typename T> unsigned bar(T p) { return p(); }`

Comment: @Dave Yeah, well, you know, [that's just, like, your opinion, man.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWdd6_ZxX8c) `short` and `long` are not nouns either - do you insist on always writing `short int` and `long int`? In my experience, that's exceedingly rare. `unsigned int` might be somewhat more common than `short int`, but still highly unusual.

Comment: I used `std::function`. Worked like a charm (and I learned something).